# Robot Framework: Calling external Keyword from Python file

Tags: frameworks, robotframework

I have a Keyword created in external python file which takes only one argument. When called in Ride, I get the error message (displayed below):

> Keyword 'CustomUtilityLibrary.CUSTOM Get List Count' expected 1 argument, got 6.

This is the keyword definition

```
def CUSTOM_Get_List_Count(self, s1):
    """Returns the total number of elements in a list
    """
    return len(s1)
```

Comment: can you show here the text version of your test that fails so that we see how you call that keyword?

Comment: For that specific case, have you considered instead using the BuiltIn keyword Get Length ? Or doing it manually by calling @{MyList.__len__()}

Answer (score 2):

This is likely due to an error in your test case. If robot is saying the function was called with six arguments, then it *was* called with six arguments.

It appears that your function takes a list as an argument. My guess is that you are calling it like this:

```
| | ${count}= | Get List Count | @{the_list}
```

The correct syntax for the last line in that example should use `$` rather than `@`:

```
| | ${count}= | Get List Count | ${the_list}
```

The reason being, when you use `@{some variable}`, it expands the variable so that each element of the list is an argument. What you want instead is to pass the whole list as a single argument, and the syntax for that is to reference the list variable with `$`.

The [robot framework user's guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#list-variables) has this to say about list variables:

> When you use a list variable in test data, then the elements of the
>   list are inserted as new cells in the test data. Thus, if the list
>   variable contains two elements, the cell containing the list variable
>   is turned into two cells with the content of the list variable.

...

> It is possible to use list variables as scalar variables containing 
>   lists simply by replacing @ with $